# Why are two requests with different clients from the same computer cache misses on cloudfront?

Tags: curl, amazon-cloudfront, http-caching

[My website](https://medstro.com) uses cloudfront for its images. If I load a webpage in a browser, and then use curl to request an image on that page, then the request with curl is a cache miss. A subsequent request with curl is a cache hit.

example: run this twice:

```
curl --verbose https://d1hvwudqvjuczb.cloudfront.net/assets/landing/splash_dickenko-2199af423f275d0784c1813cbaab5645.jpg`
```

The first time, `X-Cache` will be "Miss from cloudfront", the second time it will be "Hit from cloudfront".

So it seems cloudfront is using some aspect of the request to decide if it should refetch the image or not.

What could this criteria be?

Comment: Be sure you really are seeing what you think you're seeing, and that it's consistently repeatable. Cloudfront isn't a single thing at a single place, so not every miss will be followed by a hit. Could it be cookies? Turn on logging in Cloudfront.

Comment: There are no cookies on that domain. The behavior I'm seeing is repeatable. I would imagine since the purpose of a CDN is to not have to refetch the content for users in the same geographic area, it's reasonable for me to assume that 2 requests from the same computer won't result in a refetch the vast majority of the time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this behavior is because your requests are different.  To give you some background, Cloudfront cache varys based on the http accept-encoding header.  In your first example, in your browser, you are sending the value of gzip.  With your curl example, by default, you are not.  Therefore Cloudfront see's this objects as being unique.

Try passing the --compressed flag in curl and see if the behavior matches your browser.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html#CompressedCustomOrigin

Comment: The issue persists despite excluding headers from cache key.